# AWS EC2 instance sub directory point to direct domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-ec2, cross-domain

I have an AWS EC2 instance with elastic IP, I can point this IP as A record for Direct domain,But i'm struggling in point my EC2 sub-directory file to particular domain,

I can add this Ec2 elastic Ip as A record, Now my question is where i mention that path to point a domain?

If anyone to help this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You would do this in your virtual host configuration (within your webserver configuration). All DNS does is resolve names to IP addresses.